# In typescript generics what is use of '=' operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I'm new typescript and learning it. I have basic knowledge about typescript generics.
could someone explain me what is use of '='
operator here.

```
export interface IAdapter<T, R = T> {
  adaptToModel(resp: any): T;
  adaptFromModel(data: Partial<R>): any;
}
```

Comment: It provides a default type `T` for the parameter `R`.

Comment: ...which you'd expect to be documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), but sadly isn't.